# How to communicate between mvc partial view and angular component

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

How can i call a method inside the angular component when i change the drop down in the partial view.

I have a Partial view with a drop down control and an angular component in my mvc page. When i change my drop down in the partial view(created using razor engine), i need to trigger a method inside the angular component.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. 
Add a input on the angular component html

```
<input type="hidden"  id="selDate"/>
```

attach an onChange event in the corresponding .ts file

```
$(function () {
        $('#selDate').on('change', function () {
            var dt = $('#selDate').val();
            self.getIRData(dt);
        });
    });
```

set the value of the above control from the partial view(dropdown change event) and simulate an onChange event by adding Dispatchevent()

please let me know if you have any better workarounds